# Sections of the conormal bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, sheaf-theory, projective-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X\subset\mathbb{P}^N$ be a quadratic manifold. That is $I(X)$ is generated by quadratic polynomials $Q_1,...,Q_m$.

Let $\mathcal{I}_X$ be the ideal sheaf of $X$ and $\mathcal{I}_X/\mathcal{I}_X^2$ be the conormal bundle of $X$. Is it true that $H^0(X,\mathcal{I}_X/\mathcal{I}_X^2(2))$ has rank $m$ and that it is generated by $dQ_1,...,dQ_m$ ?

Answer (score 5):

No. The simplest example is the twisted cubic $C\subset \mathbb{P}^3$. The conormal bundle on $C\cong \mathbb{P}^1$ is $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-5)^2$. Hence $H^0(C,\mathcal{I}_C/\mathcal{I}_C^2(2))$ has dimension 4, while $I(C)$ is generated by 3 quadrics.

Comment: Sure, you are right. Thanks. Do you know if for some reason it is true for Grassmannians?

Comment: It should be decidable, but I am not brave enough to do the computations. In general, you have an exact sequence $0\rightarrow K\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X^m\rightarrow \mathcal{I}_X/\mathcal{I}_X^2(2)\rightarrow 0$, and the trouble comes from $H^1(X,K)$. If $X$ is a Grassmannian $K$ is a homogeneous vector bundle, so its cohomology should be computable.

Comment: For the Grassmannian $G$ with a universal SES, $$0\to S\to \mathcal{O}^{\oplus n}_G \to Q \to 0,$$ with $S$, resp. $Q$, locally free of rank $k$, resp. $n-k$, there is an increasing filtration on $\mathcal{I}_G/\mathcal{I}_G^2(2)$, $0 = F_0 \subset F_1 \subseteq \dots \subseteq F_{k-1} = \mathcal{I}_G/\mathcal{I}_G^2(2)$ with $F_r = \bigwedge^k(S^\vee)\otimes \bigwedge^{r-1}(S^\vee)\otimes \bigwedge^{k+1-r}(Q^\vee)$.  Thus, when $k=2$, the sheaf is just $\bigwedge^2(S^\vee)\otimes \bigwedge^2(Q^\vee)$.  By Borel-Weil-Bott, the global sections are zero or an irrep, hence surjectivity holds.

Comment: The argument above for $k=2$ *might* extend (I am not certain).  Please confer Exercise 15.32, pp. 226-227 of W. Fulton, J. Harris, "Representation Theory", GTM 129, Springer-Verlag, NY, 1991.  I am guessing that the formula they give there for $I(G)$ agrees with the formula from Borel-Weil-Bott for $H^0(G,\mathcal{I}_G/\mathcal{I}_G^2(2))$.